# Weird results using Kinect for Windsows SDK, XNA and Seated Mode

Tags: c#, xna, kinect

I have a weird problem when using Seated Mode in the Xna Example of the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit 1.5.1.

The only thing I add to the code is flowing line.

```
 this.Sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
```

[image]

Did anybody tried using XNA and Seated Mode without having this Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the XNA sample tries to draw all joints. Since only a limited set of joints is available in seated mode, the remaining joints are drawn at a default position.

Comment: Thanks the problem was that I had to remove the code where I draw all other joints

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this, with the line you added and I am pretty sure that this was just a glitch. My kinect (xbox) only had problems when I got within a foot of it, which is normal, so that was just a glitch. Hope this helps!