# kinect-Matlab weird skeletal joint on top corner while using seated mode only

Tags: matlab, kinect

I have a problem using kinect seated mode on Matlab, Its giving me a weird skeletal joint, other than the normal 10 points, on the top corner of the screen. So I would like to know what should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: I have no idea what any of this means. Please create [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This link contains a picture similar to my problem. But in my case it appears on Matlab:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343002/weird-results-using-kinect-for-windsows-sdk-xna-and-seated-mode

Comment: The link below contains a picture of the same problem I'm facing but in my case it appears on matlab:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343002/weird-results-using-kinect-for-windsows-sdk-xna-and-seated-mode